# I want to search by city and state by name and in which table i want to search that table insert city and state id

Tags: php, mysql

i want to display whole data from master table through search query and search city and state by name and in master table enter city and state id not name.

phpmyadmin mysql database in core php api.

```
if(!empty($state_id))
{
$condition .="sangh_directory.state like '$state_id%'";

}   
if(!empty($city_id))
{
$condition .="and sangh_directory.city like '$city_id%'";
}
if(!empty($searchsangh))
{
$condition .="sangh_directory.sangh_name like '$searchsangh%'";
}
$DirectoryDetailsQuery=$con->select_query("sangh_directory","*","inner join city on city.city_id=sangh_directory.city inner join country ON country.country_id=sangh_directory.country inner join state ON state.state_id=sangh_directory.state where $condition");
```

There is some error in select query table name is :sangh_directoryYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'and sangh_directory.city like 'Ahme%'' at line 1

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message you got in the last query.

Comment: state and city has unique table and i want to search whole details from sangh_directory table and that table i store city and state id .  Not store name

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
$condition = "1=1";

if(!empty($state_id)) {
    $condition .=" and sangh_directory.state like '$state_id%'";
}   
if(!empty($city_id)) {
    $condition .=" and sangh_directory.city like '$city_id%'";
}
if(!empty($searchsangh)) {
    $condition .=" and sangh_directory.sangh_name like '$searchsangh%'";
}
$DirectoryDetailsQuery=$con->select_query("sangh_directory","*","inner join city on city.city_id=sangh_directory.city inner join country ON country.country_id=sangh_directory.country inner join state ON state.state_id=sangh_directory.state where $condition");
```

I'm sorry if this is not syntactically correct, I hope you're getting the gist of it.

And if you are making a website that will be public, please watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_jKylhJtPmI) or read anything else on sql injection, as was already proposed by @Dharman.

And read on other subjects about securing a website.

Comment: try printing resulting query and look for syntactical errors. I'm not sure what select_query does, it looks like your own function…?